# How to write a backend service that runs on a timer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, rest, backend

I'm looking to create a backend application that every morning calls an external API and retrieves certain information, and then saves it to my database. I have subscriptions with both DigitalOcean and AWS so I could use either to host. I am very new to web development/javascript but have years of experience in object oriented languages and can pick it up quickly, I'm just not sure where to start for this. Thanks

Comment: doesn't matter which language u need to have a scheduler to trigger the APIA call.

Comment: Look into [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). Extremely common for task scheduling and built-in to most linux distros. If you want to use node.js, check out [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron). Same syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at [laterJs](http://bunkat.github.io/later/). Works in Node and in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Very straightforward and easy step based on AWS:

1-Create Lambda function for calling your API and retrive data and save to database.At the moment you can create Lambda function with Node.js (JavaScript), Python, and Java (Java 8 compatible).

2-Create a trigger in trigger tab for your lambda function and select CloudWatch Events for the source with one-day duration.

3-Enjoy your serverless function.

for more info read:

[Using AWS Lambda with Scheduled Events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html)

[Scenario 6: Run an AWS Lambda Function on a Schedule Using the AWS CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/RunLambdaSchedule.html)

[Schedule Expressions Using Rate or Cron](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html)